# Access Cordova function from Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

is it possible without any hacks to access Cordova plugins like the camera from the InAppBrowser?

It want access the plugins from a html site which is hosted on a web server and loaded and displayed with the Cordova InAppBrowser.

My target is an app which can be updated through changing the html source code only on an web server. After a change the Cordova app loads the modified version from the server and cache the modifications.

Are there any essential problems in this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if i can understand right, you can use jquery get method as bridge. get method's url parameter points to your original site link and appends everyting to the body.

Comment: Did you mean to load the additional information in the normal cordova app instead of the InAppBrowser?